# LPPool with trainable norm type easily result in nan gradient

Tags: python, overflow, pytorch, nan

I want to have `nn.LPPool2d(norm_type=xxx)` decide the proper `norm_type` itself by making `norm_type` trainable.

After a lot of experiments, I found that the gradient of `norm_type` can easily become `nan` even in the simplest case with single precision (not half). Here is the reproducing code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

x = torch.randn(64, 3, 32, 32, device='cuda')
y = torch.randint(0, 10, [64], device='cuda')
k = torch.tensor(1., device='cuda', requires_grad=True)
w = torch.randn(3, 10, device='cuda', requires_grad=True)

nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(F.lp_pool2d(x, k, 32).view(len(x), -1) @ w, y).backward()
print(k.grad)
```

This is simply a global LP pool with a linear layer after that. The result is

```py
tensor(nan, device='cuda:0')
```

I understand that overflow/underflow is more likely to happen because `norm_type` is mathematically on the exponent of `x`. But I'm wondering is there any way to avoid these so that I can train things normally.

I tried sacling the loss value before back propagating it, but the gradient of `norm_type` is still `nan` no matter how much I increase or decrease it (e.g. multiply 65536).

**PS:** LP Norm basically means `sumpool(x ^ norm_type) ^ (1/norm_type)` where `sumpool` is `avgpool` but do sum instead

Answer (score 0):

LPPool doesn't work as you think. Simply try `nn.LPPool2d(3, 1)(torch.randn(1, 1, 10, 10))` for an example (half `nan`).

Due to the definition, the LPPool of a negative value if undefined, except for the special cases 1, 2k and inf. Using a trainable parameter is a bad idea, unless you make sure to put a ReLU layer (or anything non-negative) first.

Even then, LPPool2d is extremely ill-behaved around 0 and below, as you can see with `nn.LPPool2d(0.01, 2)(torch.rand(1, 1, 10, 10))`. You should ensure that the trainable parameter remains something safe, say between 1 and 4.